# Configuring Ports on a Cisco Switch

Tags: cisco, switching, cisco-ios, vlan

I am very new to Cisco networking (haven't done any course either). I have been trying to learn a bit of networking myself and had no trouble in doing some of the basic stuff which i needed for my personal work. But i am planning to buy a new Cisco switch(a gigabit switch) and configure it to 2 different networks (1 being an internet and other being a separate network for a specific job). I want to configure the ports in such a way that the first few slots for normal internet and the rest for my other network. For example if its a Cisco 2950 48 port switch, the first 1-16 port for my local internet network and the ports from 17-32 for my other network. Can somebody give me a run down on how to achieve this? Sorry for such a long but basic question, i am just trying to save few $$ and learning something new. Any help would be appreciated. Cheers

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. It is not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the 2 different Vlans and Give the Access port to the 1st vlan with port 1 - 16 , And for Second vlan Give access port remaining Ports. As well you can also configure 2 different network on Single Switch .

Answer (score 0):

Vlans can separate the network traffic away from each other. For Example

```
Int range gi 0/1 - 16 
Desc Local Internet Network
Switchport access vlan 444
Switch port mode access

Int range gi 0/17 - 32  
Desc Other Network
Switchport access vlan 555
Switch port mode access
```

Of course it depends on what you plug into the ports? depends on what type of switchport it is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
Switch#configure terminal
Switch(config)#vlan 10
Switch(config-vlan)#name Local_Internet_Network
Switch(config-vlan)#exit 
Switch(config)#vlan 20
Switch(config-vlan)#name my_other_network
Switch(config-vlan)#exit

Switch(config)#interface range gigabitEthernet 0/1-16
Switch(config-if-range)#switchport mode access
Switch(config-if-range)#switchport access vlan 10
Switch(config-if-range)#exit 
Switch(config)#interface range gigabitEthernet 0/17-32
Switch(config-if-range)#switchport mode access
Switch(config-if-range)#switchport access vlan 20
Switch(config-if-range)#exit 
Switch(config)#exit 
Switch#write memory
```

and check on trunk

Answer (score -1):

The 2950 switch was a L2 switch only last time I checked so it will not be able to route between the VLANs.  You may want to consider a small firewall in order to provide the layer 3 element (routing) and block any internet traffic from hitting your LAN.  You can then also utilise a switch with this topology.
The respective switch VLANs for Internet and LAN would be connected to the relevant Internet /LAN firewall ports and your servers would be connected to the LAN.  The switch management port should also be on the trusted LAN network or a dedicated management VLAN.

Comment: Don't answer off topic questions.